# How to combine "sonar.cpd.exclusions" with the parameters in SONARQUBE Server?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

According to the structure of our project, if I want to exclude the .cs files from PY.Models \ Module1, PY.Entities \ Module1, PY.Entities \ Module2, PY.Entities \ Module3 and that "PY. Repository.ModuleN "are not going to be excluded ?. How to combine "sonar.cpd.exclusions" with the parameters in SONARQUBE Server?

```
D:\MYCOMPANY \ MYPROJECT\00_Transversal\PY.Models\PY.Models\Modulo1--
D:\MYCOMPANY\MYPROJECT\00_Transversal\PY.Models\PY.Models\Modulo2
D:\MYCOMPANY\MYPROJECT\00_Transversal\PY.Models\PY.Models\Modulo3

D:\MYCOMPANY \ MYPROJECT \01_Data\PY.Entities\PY.Entities\Module1--
D:\MYCOMPANY \ MYPROJECT \01_Data\PY.Entities\PY.Entities\Module2--
D:\MYCOMPANY \ MYPROJECT \01_Data\PY.Entities\PY.Entities\Module3--

D:\MYCOMPANY\MYPROJECT\01_Data\PY.Repository.Module1
D:\MYCOMPANY\MYPROJECT\01_Data\PY.Repository.Module2
D:\MYCOMPANY\MYPROJECT\01_Data\PY.Repository.Module3
```

[Configuration On the SONARQUBE-Duplications Tab-page Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0gRM.png)

Comment: You want to exclude them completely from analysis or only from duplication detection?

Comment: Hello, I want to exclude only Duplicate Code files located in the Templates project. On the other hand I want to exclude from the analysis the Entities project which is a very old code and we are in the process of migrating it step by step in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To exclude a file or directory entirely from analysis, go to **Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope > Files** and set `sonar.exclusions` using patterns* to describe what should be left out.

To exclude a file or directory from duplication detection, you want to set `sonar.cpd.exclusions`, as you surmised. Again, use a pattern* for this value.

Regarding whether to set this in analysis parameters or the server, I'd personally set it server-side. Just cleaner, IMO.

<sup>Recognized wildcards: `*` 0-n char; `**` 0-n directories; `?` any single character</sup>

Comment: I have configured it on the server side in the Configuration section of the Duplications tab, as I mentioned in the question initially, after running the analysis I did not report any code duplication for my Models project.
Sonar.cpd.exclusions = D: /SYACSoftware/DG/00_Transversal/DG.Models / ** / * .cs

Comment: However, I still have another pending project "Entities Project" which has very old code that we will be migrating little by little in the new version, I want to exclude it from the analysis, but without affecting other projects.It is necessary to configure each file of this project with the java syntax, so that it can exclude the whole project?, are thousands of files.

Comment: @JoseFrancisco you're setting regexes that describes the path(s) to ignore. Depending on the project structure, you should be able to do that in just a few passes.

Comment: Hello, yesterday I did the test for each module that we had to exclude in Duplications and due to our business logic for the noise generated in each analysis, I succeeded, finally the Duplication exclusion worked as follows:
    00_Transversal/PY.Models/DG.Models/**

And for the exclusion of the old code and code generated by the IDE, in the analysis no longer reported and worked like this:
    01_Files/PY.Entities/**
    ** / Properties / **

Thanks for the help. Resolved.

Comment: You might want to clarify that these "Patterns" https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#header-1 are not actually "(Java-syntax) regular expressions", but rather "Globs" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasHirsch. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The properties are set via ItemGroup in each .csproj file, this way:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SonarQubeSetting Include="sonar.cpd.exclusions">
    <Value>Models/**/*.cs</Value>
  </SonarQubeSetting>
</ItemGroup>
```